# Filter Pandas dataframe over many criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe that contains inputs and outputs of some simulations.
The inputs are ~100. For each unique combination of inputs, one unique set of outputs exists. 
I would like to filter the dataframe for each combination of inputs and retrieve the corresponding outputs.
I know how to filter a dataframe. For this small dataframe:

```
input1 input2 input3 output1 output2
   a1    a2     a3      0      1
   a1    a4     a5      2      3
   a6    a2     a3      4      5
```

I can do:`output_x = df[(df['input1']==a1) & (df['input2']==a2) & (df['input3']==a3)]['output1']`

Then I can loop through each possible input combination and retrieve all outputs.
But what if the number of inputs is very large? Is there any way for not repeating 100 times `(df['inputX']==Y)`?
I am thinking about a pandas function that retrieves all the possible combinations of values for some dataframe columns and returns the corresponding values for some other columns. Does anything like that exists?

Comment: I think you want groupby

Comment: I tried to look into that, but I don't understand how to apply it to my case

Comment: Could you show a somewhat wider dataframe and the expected output?

Comment: it's exactly like the one I pasted up there, it's just the inputs go from input1 to input100. And each row contains a different combination of inputs, both strings and numbers. 
The outputs are number, representing energy values, they can go from 0 to infinity.

Comment: So you want to get all the possible data frames for each of the combinations in Input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
mask_columns_input=df.columns.str.contains('input')
inputs=[*df.columns[mask_columns_input]]
for i,group in df.groupby(inputs):
    print(group)

      input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
0     a1     a2     a3        0        1
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
1     a1     a4     a5        2        3
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
2     a6     a2     a3        4        5
```

---

Show only Outputs:

```
mask_columns_input=df.columns.str.contains('input')
inputs=[*df.columns[mask_columns_input]]
for i,group in df.groupby(inputs):
    print(group.loc[:,~mask_columns_input])
```

**Output:**

```
   output1  output2
0        0        1
   output1  output2
1        2        3
   output1  output2
2        4        5
```

Also you can create a dict to save:

```
df_by_inputs={''.join(i):group for i,group in df.groupby(inputs)}
for key in df_by_inputs:
    print(f'df_by_inputs[{key}]')
    print('-'*45)
    print(df_by_inputs[key])

df_by_inputs[a1a2a3]
---------------------------------------------
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
0     a1     a2     a3        0        1
0     a1     a2     a3        0        1
df_by_inputs[a1a4a5]
---------------------------------------------
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
1     a1     a4     a5        2        3
1     a1     a4     a5        2        3
df_by_inputs[a6a2a3]
---------------------------------------------
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
2     a6     a2     a3        4        5
2     a6     a2     a3        4        5
```

---

```
print(df_by_inputs['a1a2a3'])
  input1 input2 input3  output1  output2
0     a1     a2     a3        0        1
0     a1     a2     a3        0        1
```

Comment: I think you want to add `.to_list()` to `inputs=[*df.columns[mask_columns_input]]`

Like this: `inputs=[*df.columns[mask_columns_input]].to_list()`

Otherwise I get an error

Comment: `[*df.columns[mask_columns_input]]` is a list. We can also use `tolist()`: `df.columns[mask_columns_input].tolist()`